# Kubernetes Node Port Service

Tags: kubernetes

I have a kubernetes cluster on bare metal with NodePort Service and 2 HAProxies balances traffic to these nodes.
when I send a request to one of these nodes, it balances traffic to other nodes in cluster. is it possible to change this behavior? I don't want to re-balance traffic.

**Update:**
we can use externalTrafficPolicy: Local

```
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  type: NodePort
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
```

Answer (score 1):

Nodeport traffic will be intercepted by kube-proxy and then it will redirect the traffic to the node which contains the Pod in a random manner. It's advisable to use Loadbalancer service instead of nodePort. This applies if you are using userspace and iptables modes

You may use [IPVS](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/07/09/ipvs-based-in-cluster-load-balancing-deep-dive/) to change the behavior

Comment: Can you really use loadbalancer services on bare metal clusters? I was under the impression that was basically just for public cloud.

Comment: @switchboard.op : Yes, we can. For production setup,  [BIG-IP](https://clouddocs.f5.com/containers/v2/kubernetes/) can be used. Also, we can use [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/) which will run inside the k8s cluster.